# Pyspark dataframe with json, iteration to create new dataframe

Tags: json, pyspark

I have data with the following format:

| customer_id | model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{color: 'red', group: 'A'},{color: 'green', group: 'B'}] |
| 2 | [{color: 'red', group: 'A'}] |

I need to process it so that I create a new dataframe with the following output:

| customer_id | color | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | A |
| 1 | green | B |
| 2 | red | A |

Now I can do this easily with python:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

newdf = pd.DataFrame([])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    s = row['model']
    x = json.loads(s)
    
    colors_list = []
    users_list = []
    groups_list = []
    
    for i in range(len(x)):
        colors_list.append(x[i]['color'])
        users_list.append(row['user_id'])
        groups_list.append(x[i]['group'])
        
    newdf = newdf.append(pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': users_list, 'group': groups_list, 'color': colors_list}))
```

How can I achieve the same result with pyspark?

I'm showing the first rows and schema of original dataframe:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|customer_id|              model |
+-----------+--------------------+
|       3541|[{"score":0.04767...|
|     171811|[{"score":0.04473...|
|      12008|[{"score":0.08043...|
|      78964|[{"score":0.06669...|
|     119600|[{"score":0.06703...|
+-----------+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows

root
 |-- user_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- groups: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) can parse a string column that contains Json data:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

data = [[1, "[{color: 'red', group: 'A'},{color: 'green', group: 'B'}]"],
        [2, "[{color: 'red', group: 'A'}]"]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ["customer_id", "model"]) \
    .withColumn("model", F.from_json("model", T.ArrayType(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())), {"allowUnquotedFieldNames": True})) \
    .withColumn("model", F.explode("model")) \
    .withColumn("color", F.col("model")["color"]) \
    .withColumn("group", F.col("model")["group"]) \
    .drop("model")
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-----+-----+
|customer_id|color|group|
+-----------+-----+-----+
|          1|  red|    A|
|          1|green|    B|
|          2|  red|    A|
+-----------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
How can I achieve the list of lists in data? The dataframe has 5 million rows, and when I try to get the two columns concatenated in that format to then process it as per your suggestion, I get error: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'unicode'>

Comment: @Sapehi my answer assumes that all json strings in the field `model` of the input dataset have the same schema: an array of color/group combinations. If there are other json strings in the column, maybe you could post an example?

Comment: I think it's because I have the original data in a spark dataframe and I don't know how to have those two columns as a list of lists, like you have in your variable 'data'. When I try I get [Row(customer_id=7286, groups=u'[{"color":'red'.....], and that format gives me error later.

Comment: @Sapehi the code should work fine with a Spark dataframe. Could you please include the output of `originalData.show()` and `originalData.printSchema()` in your question? Maybe this

Comment: Thank you. I have added that info to see if it helps :)

Comment: @Sapehi that data looks good to me. Without a way to reproduce the type error, its difficult for me to guess what's wrong.